# Can a quasiquoter 'use' variables defined in the same file it is called?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

So, I'm starting to experiment with quasiquotation and template haskell.

I want to modify an existing (large) quasiquotation code, while using the actual value of a variable defined where it is 'called'. To illustrate with a simple example:

**main.hs**

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Language.Haskell.TH
import Exp02

x = "cde"

main = do
  putStrLn [str|$x|]
```

**Exp02.hs**

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Exp02 where

import Language.Haskell.TH
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax
import Language.Haskell.TH.Quote

xpto :: String -> ExpQ
xpto [] = stringE []
xpto ('$':rest) = varE (mkName rest)
xpto str = stringE str

str = QuasiQuoter
  { quoteExp = xpto
  , quotePat = fail $ "patterns"
  , quoteType= fail $ "types"
  , quoteDec = fail $ "declarations"
  }
```

While this compiles and prints out "cde", this is not what I want. My understanding is that the resulting code in main after splicing is: `putStrLn x`. What I want is to generate `putStrLn cde` (I know this is not valid haskell code, but it's just to represent my point).

Thus, to put it in another way, I do not want to 'create a reference to the variable `x` in the main file', I want to actually use its value inside the `xpto` quasiquoter code.

I am guessing this may not be possible, since it would imply a circular reference between `main.hs` and `Exp02.hs`, and thus face the TH stage restriction. Is this correct, or is there a way to use x *value* inside the `xpto` code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, what you are trying to do isn't currently possible. From the [template haskell docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#using-template-haskell):

> You can only run a function at compile time if it is imported from another module that is not part of a mutually-recursive group of modules that includes the module currently being compiled. Furthermore, all of the modules of the mutually-recursive group must be reachable by non-SOURCE imports from the module where the splice is to be run.
>
> For example, when compiling module A, you can only run Template Haskell functions imported from B if B does not import A (directly or indirectly). The reason should be clear: to run B we must compile and run A, but we are currently type-checking A.

You are attempting to run the function (or more strictly value) `x` at compile time in the same module as `x` was defined, which is clearly stated to not be allowed.